# python solution in codewars could not pass time limit, needs optimization

Tags: python

There is a question on codewars, life without primes. I solved it yet the time issue comes up. I really cannot find a better way. The instructions go like;

Consider an array that has no prime numbers, and none of its elements has any prime digit. It would start with: [1,4,6,8,9,10,14,16,18,..]. The element at index 1 is 4.

There will be given an integer n and the task will be return the number at that index in the array. For example, solve(1) = 4, as explained above.

Here is my solution

```
def solve(n):
    no_primes=[]
    a=1
    if n == 1:
        return 4
    else:
        while True:
            try:
                no_primes[n]
                break
            except IndexError:
                if is_prime(a) == True:
                    if is_num_prime(a) == False:
                        no_primes.append(a)
                a=a+1
        return no_primes[n]

def is_prime(num):
    numbers = list(map(int, list(str(num))))
    #primes=[0,2,3,5,7,9]
    non_primes=[0,1,4,6,8,9]
    return all(list(map(lambda x:x in non_primes,numbers)))

def is_num_prime(num):
    if num == 2:
        return True
    elif num >2:
        for i in range(2,num):
            if num%i == 0:
                return False
        else:
            return True
    else:
        return False
```

Getting rid of the while loop could help but I need to keep on appending until I can reach the value from the list. A recursive for loop with using `range(1,n)` where n increases recursively may be an option but I could not write it anyways.

Comment: there should be way more efficient ways to check whether a number is prime than yours. start the for-loop at 3 instead of 2, and increment in steps of 2. Run the for-loop until the squareroot of `num` are 2 things which will immensely speed this up.

Comment: another thing that slows this down is you evaluating the generators (`list(map(int, list(str(num))))`) while it is not needed. If your next step takes an iterable as input, there is no need for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily break down this problem in simple steps:

## Generate the all the combinations

You can make an endless generator making ever-longer combinations of these digits

```
def generate_numbers():
    digits= '014689'
    for i in itertools.count(1): # ever longer number
        for x in itertools.product(digits, repeat=i): # combine the digits
            number = ''.join(x)
            if number[0] != '0':
                yield int(number)
```

> ```
> print(list(itertools.islice(generate_numbers(), 40)))
> ```

```
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 16, 18, 19, 40, 41, 44, 46, 48, 49, 60, 61, 64, 66, 68, 69, 80, 81, 84, 86, 88, 89, 90, 91, 94, 96, 98, 99, 100, 101, 104, 106, 108]
```

## Check whether a number is prime

```
def is_prime(num):
    if num in {0, 1,}:
        return False
    if num == 2:
        return True
    if not (num % 2):
        return False
    for i in range(3, round(num **.5 + 1), 2):
        if not (num % i):
            return False
    return True
```

## return the `n`th non-prime number

```
def solve(n):
    non_prime_solutions = (i for i in generate_numbers() if not is_prime(i))
    return next(itertools.islice(non_prime_solutions, n, None))
```

> ```
> [solve(i) for i in (1, 2, 10, 100)]
> ```

```
[4, 6, 44, 644]
```

Since all of this is lazily evaluated, this should go pretty fast. The one thing that can be optimised is the `is_prime`

Comment: Generating a combination list of those numbers is a great idea.

Comment: I both  tried your version of solution and my modified version(which I only changed the is_num_prime to your is_prime) and both worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
import math
import itertools

def is_prime(n):
    return all(n % i for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n) + 1)))

prime_digits = {"2", "3", "5", "7"}
def no_prime_digit(n):
    return not any(x in prime_digits for x in str(n))

def non_primes():
    return (i for i in itertools.count() if no_prime_digit(i) and not is_prime(i))

def get_non_prime(n):
    return next(x for i, x in enumerate(non_primes()) if i == n - 1)

print([(x, get_non_prime(x)) for x in [1, 10, 100]])
```

Comment: you could use a set instead of a list for the `in ["2", "3", "5", "7"]`. Making it a global variable might speed things up too, preventing from having to instantiate this list all the time

Comment: using `not any(x in {"2", "3", "5", "7"} for x in str(n))` is an alternative for the `no_prime_digit`